# Execute several commands in 1 line in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, java

I couldn't come across a solution for this. I am working on a java program which creates a .bat file and executes it afterwards. the only struggle i have is, that i have to navigate to the destination the file was written to. 
i tried with

```
cmd /K cd C:/Users/user start test.bat
```

as well as several other versions of it. none worked. the problem is that i can't have the cmd navigate the the folder and stay there to execute the start command. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start several programs or commands in one line by either using & or &&.

In your example that would become

```
cmd /K cd C:/Users/user & start test.bat
```

Alternatively you can also just start the batchfile with the full path and place the cd command in the batchfile itself. Example:

```
start c:\users\user\test.bat
```

and in test.bat include:

```
cd /d c:\users\user
:: the rest of your script
```

Comment: i tried to start the bat with `start C:/Users/user/test.bat` , but it terminated directly without starting. but with the `&` it works

Comment: Its windows, the slashes need to go the other way, so C:\Users\user\test.bat

Comment: this is working now: `cmd /K cd C:/Users/user & start test.bat`